# How to conditional update field in JSON in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

We have Student table which contains JSON in 'jsonData' column(longtext). 
We need to change value of "isHandicapped" field in json.

**Structure**:

```
{
  "data": {

    "schoolData": {

      "studentListe": [
        {
          "student": {
            "studentId": 111749,
            "isHandicapped": false
            }
        }
      ],
    },
  }
}
```

**Old Data**: "isHandicapped": false

**New Value**: "isHandicapped": "NO"

This should be conditional update as for true we need to change value as

**Old Data**: "isHandicapped": true

**New Value**: "isHandicapped": "Ja"

Primary field of table is ID.

I got following SQL Query for same but unable to understand how to add conditional update that if value is true put Ja else NO:

```
update Student 
set data = JSON_SET(data, "'$."data"."schoolData"."studentListe"[*]."isHandicapped", "?") 
where id = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would extract that field:

```
select json_extract(data, '$.data.schoolData.studentListe[*].student.isHandicapped') from Student;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_extract(data, '$.data.schoolData.studentListe[*].student.isHandicapped') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [false]                                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can use JSON_SET() to set a value for a  *specific* array member 0:

```
update student set data = json_set(data, '$.data.schoolData.studentListe[0].student.isHandicapped', 'NO');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

select json_extract(data, '$.data.schoolData.studentListe[*].student.isHandicapped') from Student;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| json_extract(data, '$.data.schoolData.studentListe[*].student.isHandicapped') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["NO"]                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But you can't use the `*` wildcard to update all array members:

```
update student set data = json_set(data, '$.data.schoolData.studentListe[*].student.isHandicapped', '"NO"');
ERROR 3149 (42000): In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and ** tokens or an array range.
```

I see a lot of questions on Stack Overflow these days about selecting or modifying JSON data in MySQL. Usually the answer is:

**You shouldn't store data in JSON format if you need to select or update fields within the JSON document.**

This type of task is easy to solve if you stored your data in normal tables and columns:

```
UPDATE StudentListe
SET isHandicapped = 'NO'
WHERE studentId = 2;
```

Comment: _You shouldn't store data in JSON format if you need to select or update fields within the JSON document._ So in what cases it can be helpful?

Comment: @James If a JSON document comprises a whole, single object that you always insert, update, or fetch in its entirety. Don't use SQL expressions to try to access sub-fields within the JSON. Use application code to serialize/deserialize the JSON into structs in your app, but your SQL code should treat it as a black box.

Answer (score 1):

The following `update` statement will do the trick:

```
UPDATE Student 
SET $.isHandicapped= CASE          
                     WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(data, "'$."data"."schoolData"."studentListe"[*]."isHandicapped")='false' 
                     THEN 'NO' 
                     ELSE 'Ja'  end
WHERE id=2;
```

Comment: UPDATE Student SET $.isHandicapped= 'NO' 
 WHERE JSON_SEARCH(data, "'$."data"."schoolData"."studentListe"[*]."isHandicapped"='false';


or 
where JSON_EXTRACT(data, "'$."data"."schoolData"."studentListe"[*]."studentId")=111749